# C++ programs taking very long time to compile in Mac OSX terminal

Tags: c++, macos, g++, osx-lion

Trivial programs are taking around 2 seconds to compile every time I run g++ in Terminal on my new MBP.  Whereas when I ssh into my school's network they compile almost instantly.  Same thing with my old macbook. Why is this one, with a brand new OS and lots of processing power, taking forever to compile.

Could this be because of where my compiler has been stored from when I downloaded g++ from Apple's website?  Or, if that is out of the question, is there any other reason why this would happen?  If so, how do I fix it?  I've googled and found nothing.

Comment: What kind of computers did your school use? Try `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to find out the processor info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't take 2 to 5 second to compile. Especially on MBP, unless it is like 10 years old maybe. I have Air (OS X 10.7.4, LLVM G++ 4.2, 1.8 GHz Intel Core i7) and it takes roughly half a second:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin air 11.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 
$ echo 'int main() { return 0; }' > ./test.cpp
$ time g++ -o test ./test.cpp 

real    0m0.561s
user    0m0.021s
sys 0m0.411s
```

You either measure time incorrectly or have something else that is screwing things up for you a big time, in which case you have to see what's going on in the system (i.e. using a profiler).